# How do I catch the fish that swallowed the key?

Tags: marvelous

In Marvelous for the Super Famicom, I'm stuck at the spot where you're supposed to free a kid from his chains using a key that fell in a river.

According to the guides I've found, the key has been swallowed by one of the fish in the pond further down the river, and you have to catch the right one to get it. However, I've been at it for some time and no luck; some fish bite, but none of them had the key, and some fish won't - maybe one of them has it?

How do I get the key for the chains to continue the game?

Update: the person playing this [video walkthrough (around 00:42:20)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_1UEgGdOXk&t=42m20s) gets the key with the first attempt, although I can't see the reason

Comment: I suggest you post your 'Update' as an answer to your own question.  No need to be embarrassed - answering your own question is acceptable and even encouraged when you discover the answer on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I have been inattentive while playing - looks like I got the key by fishing right at the beginning of the quest, then saved without realizing I had it.

This means I had the key all along when I loaded the saved game and therefore couldn't catch the right fish no matter how often I tried.

From the looks of the video playthrough mentioned in the question as well as my own experience, I guess it's always the first fish you catch after talking to your chained-up friend that has the key.